# Automatic adjustment of items in itemize to fill the slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize

In the following MWE, I manually define `\setlength\itemsep{7em}` to define the spacing between items. Is there a nice and reusable way to auto-adjust, so the slide does not look empty from the bottom? It should, however, start from the top to ensure that some animations stay on the same place in the overlays. (e.g. frame 2)

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, 
text width=3cm, thick,draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{7em}
\item 1
\item<+(1)-> 2 
\item<+(1)-> 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}{}
\begin{itemize}

\item 1

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]

\node<+(1)-> (root) [process] {root};
\node<.(1)-> (child1) [process, below of=root, xshift=-4cm] {child1};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child1.north);

\node<+(1)-> (child2) [process, below of=root, xshift=4cm] {child2};
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (root.south) -- (child2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\item <+(1)-> 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I do understand I think, but I'm not sure if this would actually look nice, if you have a lot of space between the itemize bullets. Also it would be difficult to implement, because at the moment when you set the `itemset` you do 't know yet how many items there will be, so you should store that in the `.aux` file somehow (separately for each slide) and retrieve the value for the slide in the next LaTeX run (and use it to compute the appropriate value), which is not at all trivial.

Comment: @Marjin: 3 bullets were just an example. I usually have more bullets but I am tired of manually adjusting the space in between. I cannot use `fragile` because it will change adjustment of pictures. Feel free to edit the question so it is clear to others.

Comment: `\setlength\itemsep{7em minus 6em}` ...or whatever length  minus whatever length that you like, of course.

Comment: @Curious Maybe https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=832 is what you are looking for